# I can't verify if there is a duplicate email in my local db. When I register for the first time it's working and the second time I got an error

Tags: php, database, email, duplicates

And I know my error is due to email adress because when I submit a new user to the form, it's working well but when I change all the informations except the email adress I got the error 500 Internal Server Error

My code for register

```
<?php

include 'DbConnect.php';
$objDb = new DbConnect;
$conn = $objDb->connect();

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')) ;

$first_name = $data->first_name;
$name = $data->name;
$email = $data->email;
$password = $data->password;
$password_confirm = $data->password_confirm;


$password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

switch($method){
    case "POST":

        $sql = "INSERT INTO register(name, first_name, email, password_hash) VALUES ('$name', '$first_name', '$email', '$password_hash')";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            $response = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Record created succesfully. '];
        }else{
            $response = ['status' => 0 , 'message' => 'Failed to create record. '];
        }

        echo json_encode($response);
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Sp what does your http server's error log file say what the issue is?

Comment: And ... by the way ... I fail to see _any_ attempt to prevent duplicate entries with the same email address. So most likely you simply have a unique index on that column and "forgot" to prevent what you ask in the question's title ...

Comment: For prepared statement, the placeholders should be either like `?` or `:placeholdername` , and there should be parameter binding (say in an array format)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have duplicate email, you should change your SQL code and remove unique index on the email field.
and if you don't want, you can use below code to prevent duplicate emails to your database:

```
<?php

include 'DbConnect.php';
$objDb = new DbConnect;
$conn = $objDb->connect();

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')) ;

$first_name = $data->first_name;
$name = $data->name;
$email = $data->email;
$password = $data->password;
$password_confirm = $data->password_confirm;

$email_duplicate = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM register WHERE email = '$email')";
if($email_duplicate) {
    exit("the $email already used, please enter another email.");
}

$password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

switch($method){
    case "POST":

        $sql = "INSERT INTO register(name, first_name, email, password_hash) VALUES ('$name', '$first_name', '$email', '$password_hash')";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            $response = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Record created succesfully. '];
        }else{
            $response = ['status' => 0 , 'message' => 'Failed to create record. '];
        }

        echo json_encode($response);
        break;
}
?>
```